# How close popup by click on background

Tags: popup, hide, fadeout

i have simple dropdown, and i need to hide (fadeout) it by clicking on the document

[image]

this is my jquery code:

```
var expandCheckbox = $('.filterShow'),
    formCheckbox = $('.checkboxWrap');
expandCheckbox.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(formCheckbox).fadeOut(200);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(formCheckbox).fadeIn(100);
    }
});

$('body').not('.filterShow, .checkboxWrap').click(function() {
    $(formCheckbox).fadeOut(100);
});
```

[SEE JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9z9v6fv9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove "e.preventDefault" which has no use here, add "return false" to prevent event propagation to its parent, use "document" instead of "body" as the selector for fading the dropdownlist upon clicking anywhere on the document.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    expandCheckbox = $('.filterShow'),
    formCheckbox = $('.checkboxWrap');
    expandCheckbox.click(function (e) {

        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            formCheckbox.fadeOut(200);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            formCheckbox.fadeIn(100);
        }
        return false;
    });

    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if (expandCheckbox.hasClass('active')) {
            expandCheckbox.removeClass('active');
            formCheckbox.fadeOut(200);
        }
        return false;
    });

    formCheckbox.find('input:checkbox').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: and if do not close the popup after clicking on the checkbox?

Comment: The checkboxes disappear due to the document.click event elevated from the checkbox click event, so in the checkbox click event, stop the propagation. See added code.

Comment: we can do it with all of .checkboxWrap - div?

Comment: It should be formCheckbox.find('input:checkbox'). Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/rwoy2qqd/2/